# Ionic - Menu and disabled Input Elements

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am trying to use a `ion-menu` and put several input elements (e.g.`ion-toggle`) within the menu. The elements are rendered fine, but the input controls are disabled.

Example Menu:

```html
<ion-menu side="start" menuId="settings" contentId="main">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="light">
      <ion-title>Settings Menu</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons slot="end">
        <ion-button (click)="onOpenCloseSettingsMenu()">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" icon="close-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Toggle1</ion-label>
        <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="toggleValue"></ion-toggle>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
        <ion-select placeholder="Select One">
          <ion-select-option value="f">Female</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="m">Male</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

The input elements work in my primary menu (which is opened via `ion-menu-button`). The menu mentioned here is a secondary menu (different `side` than the primary) and opened via `onOpenCloseSettingsMenus()`:

```js
async onOpenCloseSettingsMenu() {
    await this.menuController.enable(true, 'settings');
    await this.menuController.toggle('settings');

    // this.menuController.open('settings');
  }
```

Not sure what is wrong here.

**EDIT**

The problem arises from the situation, that I have a menu in the `app.html`

```html
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu contentId="main" menuId="first">
  ...
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

When I put the `settings` menu in `app.html` the menu items are enabled. But since this menu should be page specific, this is not a solution to my problem.

Changing `contentId` of the `settings` menu to `mainTwo` and changing the template where the `settings` menu appears like this does not work either:

```html
<ion-menu side="start" menuId="settings" contentId="mainTwo">
...
</ion-menu>
```

So, the menu is shown, but is disabled (i.e. items are not clickable at all).

Comment: Any news on this?